# Someone put malicious code with "~" on my website

Tags: apache, url-routing

I made my website in [www.mantarrayamx.com](http://www.mantarrayamx.com) and everything worked well, but today I got a message from google telling me that someone is misusing my website through this address:
[Http://www.mantarrayamx.com/~stechies/Blessin/ba/](http://www.mantarrayamx.com/~stechies/Blessin/ba/)
Does anyone know how I can solve this security problem please?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found that the ~stechies means, home directory of a user perhaps "stechies". I found a website with the same a domain name https://www.stechies.com/ I am not sure if they are behind this or they are hacked as well.

Any help to stop this redirection is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by contacting my web hosting provider, they updated the php and mysql versions of your linux server,
**In a nutshell you do not have enough privileges to do it for yourself, only your web hosting provider can solve it**