# My domain is being used to serve a phishing site. They have used used Apache redirection I think. Could somebody rescue me?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-routing, phishing

I received email from Google search console saying my website contains social engineering contents. Sample URL is,

http://www.sanenthusiast.com/~stechies/Blessin/ba/index.php

Safety tip **For your own safety do not type anything in the page.**

Somebody hosted a mockup site of Google drive login page on these links. How to get rid of this? I have thoroughly checked my webserver an I dont see any of these folders or files. Looks likes `~stechies/` could be some other webserver and I guess using Apache they have pointed `~stechies/Blessin/ba/index.php` and `~stechies/Blessin/ba/` to my webserver `sanenthusiast.com/`?

Is this correct? It will be of great help if someone could help to stop this redirection.

I checked who owns stechies and found https://www.stechies.com/ Are they behind this phishing scam? Or possibly someone else has hacked them?

Edit:
Another user in stackoverflow posted similar issue on his site - [Someone put malicious code with "~" on my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576266/someone-put-malicious-code-with-on-my-website/41587500#41587500)

Comment: It looks like it's using Apache's [mod_userdir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html), have you checked for these files in /home/stetchies/ or similar? And I wouldn't assume the site you linked is related.

Comment: yes, I lookup my root dir. There no such user as stechies. I will check again and let you know. Thank you for looking into this. Another user posted similar issue here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576266/someone-put-malicious-code-with-on-my-website/41587500#41587500

Answer (score 0):

Tried all possible ways to mitigate the issue. But it was very hard to get rid of the URL redirect. My site runs on WordPress. I can confirm that WordPress was intact and not compromised. The possible issue is with the hosting account or the hosting provider itself.

Checked hidden file in the hosting account root directory, no where ~stechies/Blessin/ba/ to be seen. Finally I ended up migrating to a new hosting provider. Copied only mail and WordPress backup. Once done, the URL redirect is not working now. Submitted my site again for review and Google cleared the error and no more warning comes up.

This still not a effective solution but Google reporting Social engineering content on the site caused panic and I had very less time to respond.